# Iterative way to delete the root node of a binary tree in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, binary-search, binary-data, root-node

```
void Bst_DeleteStudent(struct BstStudent** root, char student_name[]){
    struct BstStudent* current = *root;
    struct BstStudent* parent = NULL;
    int flag = 0;
    int i;

    while(current != NULL){
        if(strcmp(current->name, student_name) > 0){
            parent = current;
            current = current->left;
        }
        else if(strcmp(current->name, student_name) < 0){
            parent = current;
            current = current->right;
        }
        else{
            flag = 1;
            //If node has no children
            if(current->left == NULL && current->right == NULL){
                if(parent->left == current){
                    parent->left = NULL;
                }
                else{
                    parent->right = NULL;
                }
                free(current);
                return;
            }
            //If current has one child
            else if((current->left == NULL && current->right != NULL) || (current->left != NULL && current->right == NULL)){
                //If node has a right child 
                if(current->right != NULL && current->left != NULL){
                    if(parent->right == current){
                        parent->right = current->right;
                    }
                    else if(parent->left == current){
                        parent->left = current->right;
                    }
                }
                //If node has a left child
                else if(current->left != NULL && current->right == NULL){
                    if(parent->right == current){
                        parent->right = current->left;
                    }
                    else if(parent->left == current){
                        parent->left = current->left;
                    }
                }
                free(current);
                return;
            }
            //If current has two children
            else{
                struct BstStudent* swap_this = current->right;
                struct BstStudent* swap_this_prev = current;

                while(swap_this->left != NULL){
                    swap_this_prev = swap_this;
                    swap_this = swap_this->left;
                }

                strcpy(current->name, swap_this->name);
                current->id = swap_this->id;
                for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                    current->marks[i] = swap_this->marks[i];
                }

                if(swap_this_prev->left == swap_this){
                    swap_this_prev->left = swap_this->right;
                }
                else if(swap_this_prev->right == swap_this){
                    swap_this_prev->right = swap_this->right;
                }
                free(swap_this);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        printf("\nStudent named '%s' removed\n", student_name);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nNo student named '%s' is found in the list!\n", student_name);
    }
}
```

Hi guys, I'm currently want to make a delete function for a binary search tree implementation which sorts the nodes based on names, alphabetically. My code works perfectly fine can delete most of the time. The code only gives a segmentation fault in a specific case when I want to delete the root node and the root node has only one child or no children. Every other deletion works. Can you guys please help me?

Comment: Did you try stepping in your code using a debugger?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. You make it hard on us when we can't grab your code, compile and test the actual failure modes you are experiencing. An MCVE is required for all "help me find this bug" questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

struct BstStudent{
    char name[50];
    int id;
    float marks[5];
    struct BstStudent* left;
    struct BstStudent* right;
};

void Bst_IntroduceStudent(struct BstStudent** root, char student_name[], int student_id){
    struct BstStudent* new_student = (struct BstStudent*)malloc(sizeof(struct BstStudent));
    struct BstStudent* current = *root;
    struct BstStudent* previous = NULL;
    int i;

    strcpy(new_student->name, student_name);
    new_student->id = student_id;
    new_student->left = NULL;
    new_student->right = NULL;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        new_student->marks[i] = 0;
    }

    //Check if the tree is empty
    if(*root == NULL){
        *root = new_student;
    }
    else{
    //If not empty, go through the tree until we find the right spot for the student
    while(current != NULL){
        if(strcmp(current->name, new_student->name) > 0){
            previous = current;
            current = current->left;
        }
        else if(strcmp(current->name, new_student->name) < 0){
            previous = current;
            current = current->right;
        }
        else if(strcmp(current->name, new_student->name) == 0){
            printf("\n** A student with that name already exists! **\n");
            free(new_student);
            return;
        }
    }
    //If we found the right node after which we want to place the student, decide if place right or left
    if(strcmp(previous->name, new_student->name) > 0){
        previous->left = new_student;
    }
    else{
        previous->right = new_student;
    }
}  
}

void Bst_DeleteStudent(struct BstStudent** root, char student_name[]){
    struct BstStudent* current = *root;
    struct BstStudent* parent = NULL;
    int flag = 0;
    int i;

    while(current != NULL){
        if(strcmp(current->name, student_name) > 0){
            parent = current;
            current = current->left;
        }
        else if(strcmp(current->name, student_name) < 0){
            parent = current;
            current = current->right;
        }
        else{
            flag = 1;
            //If node has no children
            if(current->left == NULL && current->right == NULL){
                if(parent->left == current){
                    parent->left = NULL;
                }
                else{
                    parent->right = NULL;
                }
                free(current);
                return;
            }
            //If current has one child
            else if((current->left == NULL && current->right != NULL) || (current->left != NULL && current->right == NULL)){
                //If node has a right child 
                if(current->right != NULL && current->left != NULL){
                    if(parent->right == current){
                        parent->right = current->right;
                    }
                    else if(parent->left == current){
                        parent->left = current->right;
                    }
                }
                //If node has a left child
                else if(current->left != NULL && current->right == NULL){
                    if(parent->right == current){
                        parent->right = current->left;
                    }
                    else if(parent->left == current){
                        parent->left = current->left;
                    }
                }
                free(current);
                return;
            }
            //If current has two children
            else{
                struct BstStudent* swap_this = current->right;
                struct BstStudent* swap_this_prev = current;

                while(swap_this->left != NULL){
                    swap_this_prev = swap_this;
                    swap_this = swap_this->left;
                }

                strcpy(current->name, swap_this->name);
                current->id = swap_this->id;
                for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                    current->marks[i] = swap_this->marks[i];
                }

                if(swap_this_prev->left == swap_this){
                    swap_this_prev->left = swap_this->right;
                }
                else if(swap_this_prev->right == swap_this){
                    swap_this_prev->right = swap_this->right;
                }
                free(swap_this);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1){
        printf("\nStudent named '%s' removed\n", student_name);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nNo student named '%s' is found in the list!\n",    student_name);
    }
}

void Bst_Marks(struct BstStudent *student){ 
    printf("Insert the student marks!\n");

    //Declaring variables for looping and inserting marks
    int i;
    float mark;

    //Loop through each module (element) in the marks array and inserting a mark
    for( i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("Insert the mark for the %d module!\n",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&mark);
        student->marks[i] = mark;
    }
}

void Bst_IntroMarks(struct BstStudent* root, char student_name[]){
    struct BstStudent* current = root;
    int flag = 0;

    while(current != NULL){
        if(strcmp(current->name, student_name) > 0){
            current = current->left;
        }
        else if(strcmp(current->name, student_name) < 0){
            current = current->right;
        }
        else{
            Bst_Marks(current);
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0){
        printf("\nThere is no student named: %s\n", student_name);
    }  
}

void Bst_SearchPrint(struct BstStudent* root, char student_name[]){
    struct BstStudent* current = root;
    int i, flag = 0;

    while(current != NULL){
        if(strcmp(current->name, student_name) > 0){
            current = current->left;
        }
        else if(strcmp(current->name, student_name) < 0){
            current = current->right;
        }
        else{
            printf("\n----------------\n");
            printf("Name:   %s\n", current->name);
            printf("Student ID: %d\n", current->id);
            for(i=0; i<5; i++){
                printf("Module %d:   %f\n", i+1, current->marks[i]);
            }
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0){
        printf("\nThere is no student named: %s\n", student_name);
   }
}

void Bst_PrintAll(struct BstStudent** root){
    struct BstStudent* temp = *root;
    int i;

    if(temp == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        Bst_PrintAll(&temp->left);
        printf("\n----------------\n");
        printf("Name:   %s\n", temp->name);
        printf("Student ID: %d\n", temp->id);
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
            printf("Module %d:   %f\n", i+1, temp->marks[i]);
        }
        Bst_PrintAll(&temp->right);
    }
}

void leftRotateBinary(struct BstStudent** current){
    struct BstStudent* temp;
    struct BstStudent* original;
    struct BstStudent* right;

    if(*current == NULL || (*current)->right == NULL){
        return;
    }

    original = *current;
    right = original->right;

    temp = (struct BstStudent*)malloc(sizeof(struct BstStudent));
    int i;
    strcpy(temp->name, original->name);
    temp->id = original->id;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        temp->marks[i] = original->marks[i];
    }

    strcpy(original->name,right->name);
    original->id = right->id;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        original->marks[i] = right->marks[i];
    }    

    temp->right = right->left;
    temp->left = original->left;
    original->right = right->right;
    original->left = temp;

    free(right);
}

void rightRotateBinary(struct BstStudent** current){
    struct BstStudent* temp;
    struct BstStudent* original;
    struct BstStudent *left;

    if(*current == NULL || (*current)->left == NULL){
        return;
    }

    original = *current;
    left = original->left;

    temp = (struct BstStudent*)malloc(sizeof(struct BstStudent));
    int i;

    strcpy(temp->name, original->name);
    temp->id = original->id;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        temp->marks[i] = original->marks[i];
    }

    strcpy(original->name, left->name);
    original->id = left->id;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        original->marks[i] = left->marks[i];
    }

    temp->left = left->right;
    temp->right = original->right;
    original->left = left->left;
    original->right = temp;

    free(left);
}

void balanceBinary(struct BstStudent **root){
    struct BstStudent* current = *root;
    int expected, i, odd_node;
    int num_nodes = 0;

    while(current != NULL){
        while(current->left != NULL){
            rightRotateBinary(&current);
        }
        current = current->right;
        num_nodes++;
    } 

    expected = num_nodes - (pow(2,(floor(log2(num_nodes+1)))) - 1);
    current = *root;

    for(i=0; i<expected; i++){
        leftRotateBinary(&current);
        current = current->right;
    }

    current = *root;
    num_nodes = num_nodes - expected;
    odd_node = (num_nodes+1)/2;
    while(odd_node > 1){
        leftRotateBinary(&(*root));

        for(i=0; i<(odd_node-1); i++){
            leftRotateBinary(&(current->right));
            current = current->right;
        }
        odd_node = (odd_node+1)/2;
    }
}



int main(){
//Pointer to root node initially points to empty tree
struct BstStudent* rootPtr = NULL;

    int user_choice;
    char new_name[20], new_name2[20], marks_name[20], report_name[20], delete_name[20];
    int new_ID, new_ID2;

    //Keep displaying the menu until the user decides to quit the program
    do{
        //Main menu
        printf("\nManage data for students: (Type an option and press ENTER)\n");
        printf("1) Introduce new student:\n");
        printf("2) Remove student:\n");
        printf("3) Introduce marks for a student:\n");
        printf("4) Print report for a student:\n");
        printf("5) Print report for all students:\n");
        printf("6) Save to a file:\n");
        printf("7) Retrieve data from a file:\n");
        printf("8) Quit\n\n");

        //Ask the user to choose from the menu options above
        scanf("%d", &user_choice);

        switch(user_choice){
            case 1:
                //Ask the user for the name and ID of student he wants to introduce
                printf("Insert the name of new student: \n");
                scanf("%s", new_name);
                printf("Insert the id of new student: \n");
                scanf("%d", &new_ID);
                Bst_IntroduceStudent(&rootPtr, new_name, new_ID);
                balanceBinary(&rootPtr);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Insert the name of student you want to remove: \n");
                scanf("%s", delete_name);
                Bst_DeleteStudent(&rootPtr, delete_name);
                balanceBinary(&rootPtr);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Insert the ID of the student you want to introduce marks for!\n");
                scanf("%s", marks_name);
                //Insert the marks
                Bst_IntroMarks(rootPtr, marks_name);
                break;
                break;
            case 4:
                //Ask the user which student's report want to be printed
                printf("Insert the ID of the student you want to print a report!\n");
                scanf("%s", report_name);
                //Print the report for that student
                Bst_SearchPrint(rootPtr, report_name);
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Print report of all students:\n\n");
                Bst_PrintAll(&rootPtr);
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                //Quit the program
                printf("\nProgram ended!\n");
                return 0;
                default:
                break;
        }
    }
    while(user_choice!= 8);
return 0;
}
```

Here is my entire code, I didnt want to put it bc its really long, but if this can give you guys better context for helping me out, I would be really really glad

Comment: please be kind enough to post the entire delete function, the final vesion that works!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the left/right node of NULL(parent), in the case of deletion of root node.

Add a condition before accessing parent whether parent is NULL or not if parent is not NULL then only assign the value to its node pointer.

For example

```
if(parent != NULL) {
    if(parent->left == current){
        parent->left = NULL;
    }
    else{
        parent->right = NULL;
    }
}
```

Add the same condition in other parts of code also.

Comment: Actually, a single test for whether `current == *root` should be sufficient to handle this special case. It needs to be set to NULL yes? Or is root to be left alone and it's left/right elements NULL'd? Without additional context, it's impossible to say.

Comment: And what happens if(parent == NULL) ? How should I disconnect the root? Thank you for your help, it means a lot

Comment: I made it work finally. Thank you guys for your help

Comment: @MinhNguyenNhat, can you please post the final working code. Much appreciated.